# Scaling Probability Density Functions

Tags: probability, statistics

The Maxwell-Boltzmann Distribution, with probability density function (pdf),

$$ f_{MB}(v) = \sqrt{ \frac{2}{\pi} } \Bigg( \frac{m}{k_B T}
 \Bigg)^{3/2} v^2 \exp \Bigg(- \frac{1}{2} mv^2 \cdot \frac{1}{k_B T} \Bigg) $$

is used to describe the distribution of speeds in an ideal gas. Now of course for a pdf, the area is 1 so $\int_0^{\infty} f_{MB}(v) \, \mathrm{d}v = 1$. But chemists and physicists often refer to the integral being the number of particles so the above formula becomes

$$ N f_{MB}(v) = N \sqrt{ \frac{2}{\pi} } \Bigg( \frac{m}{k_BT} \Bigg)^{3/2} v^2 \exp\Bigg(- \frac{1}{2} mv^2 \cdot \frac{1}{k_B T} \Bigg) $$

where $N$ is the number of particles, so that $\int_0^{\infty} N f_{MB}(v) \, \mathrm{d}v = N$. This jump makes me feel uneasy. How valid an adjustment is this and what assumptions does it make to jump from one to the other? I would be suspecting that the $N$ particles would have to be independent of each other and non-interacting. As a result, rather than probability density being the $y$-axis, it is instead "number of particles" or "fraction of particles" (possibly incorrect if scaling) used as the $y$-axis

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sorry having trouble getting the maths to appear (just formula for distribution). Trying to clarify if the jump from f(v) to Nf(v) is appropriate and what assumptions are made. f(v) is a pdf

Comment: I suggest you ask it on physics SE instead. A lot of physics-related context is required.

Comment: ‘ This jump makes me feel uneasy. How valid an adjustment is this and what assumptions does it make to jump from one to the other?’

Interpretations and applications will depend heavily on the context.

Comment: There is no 'jump' at all. $f_{MB}(v)\,dv$ describes the percentage of particles having velocity in the interval  $[v,v+dv]\,.$  If that is a percentage the total of it is $1$. ***Question/Hint:*** How many particles have their velocity in that interval and what is their total number? This has nothing to do with interaction of particles. They are permitted to collide. MB describes only the distribution of their velocities. That's it.

Comment: It probably helps also to consider that the MB distribution is only realistic when $N$ is very large since it is a continuous idealisation of an otherwise discrete distribution.

Comment: I think it's because P(X=x) = 0, so how do we assign numbers for N(X=x)